# ID value generating colon before actual value

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-service-cloud

In a salesforce login form, input field have ID value, and ID value is adding the prefix of parent div, please see the code below:

```
<apex:inputText id="login__idvalue" value="{!Inputvalue}" />
```

Expected result in web page is:

```
<input type="text" id="login_idvalue" value="ABC value" />
```

But since the input is wrapped in a `DIV` its generating the following:

```
<input type="text" id="test:login_idvalue" value="ABC value" />
```

How do I remove/avoid that `test:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal behavior, the Visualforce component id's don't correspond directly to the ids of their corresponding DOM elements.

One option would be to use the `$Component` variable in your Visualforce to get the DOM id generated for a given component. see: [Using $Component to Reference Components from JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm#pages_access)

Or you could use HTML directly in you visualforce, where the id value will be passed through unchanged. There would be more work doing it this way vs using a standard component, but it might be worth considering.